# In Nativescript how can I achieve a vertically aligned label text using StackLayout

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I need something like this:

[image: ideal output]

But this is what I have at the moment:

[image: current output]

```
.rotate {
transform: rotate(-90deg);
font-size: 16px;
color: #FFFFFF; 
}
```

This is my code:

```
<StackLayout backgroundColor="#3C414B" width="12%" height="100%" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" (tap)="openDrawer('Right')">
   <StackLayout class="rotate" orientation="horizontal">
      <Label class="fa" style="margin-right: 10px" text="&#xf067;"></Label>
      <Label width="100%" class="" text="New Category" textwrap="false"></Label>
   </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that rotations are applied after sizing. Your `width` is now vertical and your `height` is horizontal. If you change the background colour of the label, this will become more apparent.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the height explicitly to the width of the element, transform doesn't take care of that by default.

Or you may even consider using an image, [here](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/present-text-or-label-vertically-90-deg/7076) is a related thread from Forums.

Comment: But i cannot give it explicit height or either width because i want to show that Label 12% width of my screen and 100% height as it keep staying at the center of the vertical screen.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you rotate inner `<StackLayout class="rotate" ...>`, but it still get width limit of outer `<StackLayout width="12%" ...>`
Try so:

```
<StackLayout class="rotate" backgroundColor="#3C414B" width="100%" height="12%" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center">
            <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
                <Label class="fa" style="margin-right: 10px" text="&#xf067;"></Label>
                <Label text="New Category" textwrap="false" backgroundColor="yellow"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
```

Or try to find solution with other layout type. For example, `AbsoluteLayout`

Comment: you havent checked that my width for that Label is fixed 12% that is the container <StackLayout> is having i cannot give that Label 100% width so that it is been try to use vertically...its not the width 100% or height 12% its about the width only 12th % and the height is 100% so that the text come across clearly vertically using the height. 
And by the way <AbsoluteLayout> have same problem of not getting the space of height and the text is wrapping automatically no matter what!